# Feedburner is Displaying an Inactive Email Address When Logged In

Tags: feedburner

I have set up a Feedburner subscription through my Google account login. For some reason Feedburner displays an old inactive email address in the top right when logged into Feedburner. I'm concerned since I don't have access to this email account. If for any reason I need to move my Feedburner Feed I'm concerned I'll need to access this email account which is impossible. My email address is correct in every other Google account, profile etc. and has been updated to a working and correct email address. How can I change this? Do I need to be concerned?